# Post request has no params

Tags: java, rest, http-post

some strange situation I have and need your help.

For clear understand communication flow (simple client-server communication):
3rd provider send POST callback (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) ---> to API. API take all parameters from POST request (**here are issue** - no params).

What I see in response payload on 3rd provider (what he did):

```
<form name="redirectToCaForm" action="http://someURL/api/consentFailed" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
</form>
<script>
  document.redirectToCaForm.submit();
</script>
```

In API code looks like this to catch request and it params:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/api/consentFailed",
            consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<?> postConsentFailedCallback(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                       @RequestParam final MultiValueMap<String, String> formParams) {
...
...
}
```

But not any formParams came. Request working only with written consume. Also I see and know what 3rd provider send, but why API doesn't catch params? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Which params/inputs do you expect to be catched? Is it the complete form of yours, or you trimmed inputs in it?

Comment: I would expect to be catched any params, because 3rd provider could provide different params :/ that'w why I would like to use MultiValueMap instead to write different endpoints. Have tried some, and result is same, no params.